# Firebase Storage Rules matching filename without Extension to User ID

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to be able to store images for profiles with the filename as the user id, which I want to then use in my code so that when I find the user id i can fetch based on the ID. I'm converting the filename in my code to the user ID and I'm able to store it without a problem. I was to enforce this convention using Firebase Storage Rules and I'm having trouble trying to get the name of the file

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    },
    match /images/profile/full/{imagename}.*{
        allow read;
      allow write: if imagename == request.auth.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to use the above rule, but when I tried to publish it I had received error

> Error saving rules - Line 6: Unexpected ','.; Line 7: Missing 'match'
> keyword before path.; Line 7: Unexpected '.'.; Line 7: mismatched
> input '.' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}; Line 12: Unexpected '}'.

Is it possible to use to enforce the name of the file, and how would i be able to set the rule to ensure that the filename is the same as the user id and allow read access to everyone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely won't work:

```
match /images/profile/full/{imagename}.*
```

You can only match full path segments, not partials like you're doing here.

So that means you have to match the full path segment, including the extension, and then sort it out in the rule's condition. Luckily the captures path segment is a string, so we can use regular expressions for this.

Something like:

```
match /images/profile/full/{imagename} {
  allow write: if imagename.matches("^"+request.auth.uid);
}
```

Comment: You will also want to change or remove the `match /{allPaths=**}`, since that allows full read and write access to all files all the time, regardless of any other rules.

Comment: Thanks Frank and Doug,  I was hoping you guys would see this. Just another question: If I need to match full segments does that mean that i need to have a rule for each document path ? is it possible to say if you have access to the parent document then you have access to all the descendants ?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, possibly because Firebase storage rules don't support multiline regex.

Try this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /users/{fileName} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && fileName.matches(request.auth.uid +'.*');
    }
  }
}
```